# std::cout gives different output from qDebug

Tags: c++, qt, cout, qtcore, qdebug

I am using Qt, and I have an `unsigned char *bytePointer` and want to print out a number-value of the current byte. Below is my code, which is meant to give the int-value and the hex-value of the continuous bytes that I receive from a machine attached to the computer:

```
int byteHex=0;
byteHex = (int)*bytePointer;

qDebug << "\n  int: " //this is the main issue here. 
          << *bytePointer;

std::cout << " (hex:  "
          << std::hex
          << byteHex
          << ")\n";

}
```

This gives perfect results, and I get actual numbers, however this code is going into an API and I don't want to use Qt-only functions, such as qDebug. So when I try this:

```
int byteHex=0;
byteHex = (int)*bytePointer;

std::cout << "\n  int: " //I changed qDebug to std::cout
          << *bytePointer;

std::cout << " (hex:  "
          << std::hex
          << byteHex
          << ")\n";

}
```

The output does give the hex-values perfectly, however the int-values return symbols (like ☺, └, §, to list a few).

My question is: How do I get `std::cout` to give the same output as `qDebug`?

EDIT: for some reason the symbols only occur with a certain Qt setting. I have no idea why it happened but it's fixed now.

Comment: Note that this will work once, then `cout` is stuck in hex mode because you don't reset it.

Comment: Is it a Qt application? If yes, why not qDebug? If not, why did you use it earlier at all?

Comment: @SebastianRedl that was the problem, actually. I just didn't add std::dec afterwards. I'm pretty embarrassed, but thank you!

Comment: @lpapp Right now it is in Qt, but I am now moving it to Visual Studio, because it's part of an API.

Comment: Qt can be developed in Visual Studio just fine. If you mean WinAPI, yikes! ;-)

Comment: What do you mean? qDebug surely wouldn't work in VS, right? I'm not sure, I've never actually tried it.

Comment: [There are tricks and you could also use qInstallMsgHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184590/how-to-view-qdebug-in-visual-studio). There is even a Qt plugin for Visual Studio both Qt 4 as well as Qt 5. What problem exactly are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out in comment, you change the outputting to hex, but you do not actually set it back here:

```
std::cout << " (hex:  "
          << std::hex
          << byteHex
          << ")\n";
```

You will need to apply this afterwards:

```
std::cout << std::dec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard output streams will output any character type as a character, not a numeric value. To output the numeric value, convert to a non-character integer type:

```
std::cout << int(*bytePointer);
```

Comment: Or just `byteHex` again. The variable is just misnamed.

Comment: I think since I used std::hex after that, it makes the `*bytePointer` also a hex value, for some strange reason. So both values end up being hex. If I remove the `std::hex` both of them become integer values.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes, I guess it is somewhat misnamed; I just named it that because that's the variable I was going to use just for the hex code.

Comment: To make cout back to decimal nubmers, use cout << std::dec

Comment: Thank you for helping, however it's not necessarily the answer so I won't mark it as one, but I did give an upvote :P